# How to Transfer data outside a Function

Tags: javascript, function

Would like to ask if how can I transfer the rowObject data outside the function.

```
document.getElementById('buttonn').addEventListener("click", () => {
    XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data, 'out.xlsx');
    if(selectedFile){
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
        fileReader.onload = (event)=>{
         let result = event.target.result;
         let workbook = XLSX.read(result,{type:"binary"});
         console.log(workbook);
         workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
              let rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);
              console.log(rowObject);
              data = rowObject;
              // document.getElementById("jsondata").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(rowObject,undefined,4)
            //   document.getElementById("jsondata").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(rowObject,undefined,4)
              

         });
        }
    }
});

const resultData = rowObject;
```

Up here is im setting rowobject as the new resultData so i can use it in my table.
Thanks!!

Comment: in an event handler, the only way is to "pollute" the global namespace - why do you need to do this?

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX Im tryng to get the data outside the function, so i can use it in the table that will show the list array. Thanks

Comment: then "transfer" the data to global namespace (window.something = rowObject *inside the success function*) of course, then the rest of the code won't know when the data is there - such is the pitfalls of asnynchrony

Answer (score 0):

assign it globally, you could just set it on the window:

```
window["rowObject"] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);
```

there it is reachable everywhere (if this is what you meant)

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the EventHandler, you have to define a global variable: `let globalData;`
Then, you can assign this variable inside of your EventHandler and use it anywhere in your code.

Here's an example of global/local variables:

```
let i_am_global = 0;

function f() {
  let i_am_local = 1;
  i_am_global = 2;
}

console.log(i_am_global);
f();
console.log(i_am_global);
```